# Problem with store.js

Tags: expresso-store

I'm using Expresso Store and having problems with store.js. It loads but returns an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

On line 142.

I've built my store locally using Expresso Store and all is working with store.js loading and functioning correctly. I've then made a complete export of all files and DB to a remote staging server as a complete replica and everything is working apart from store.js. It is returning the above error and I can't add any items to my cart.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looked to be my own fault as I'd written a custom extension to interact with Store. It was this that was causing the problem. store.js is loading fine now.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that you can look at.

- Clear your cache in your browser
- Make sure that you are calling jQuery in your header area.
- Make sure all of your theme paths are correct.
- Reupload the store theme folder.